# Keras and tensorflow in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to develop a neural network model in R, and I need keras and tensorflow for that, but it seems quite difficult to actually get those libraries in R. What I currently have tried is:

- downloaded python
- downloaded anaconda
- ran `install_keras()` and `install_tensorflow()` in RStudio

I get many errors, but one of the main errors I now seem to get when I try to run my neural network model is:

> Error: Valid installation of TensorFlow not found.

even though it does seem like I have tensorflow installed, since when I ran `install_tensorflow()` it said installation successful.

Edit 1:
When I run both `keras::install_keras()` and `tensorflow::install_tensorflow()`, I get the following error:

> Error in virtualenv_install(envname = envname, packages = packages, ignore_installed = pip_ignore_installed,  : 'r-tensorflow' exists but is not a virtual environment

And when I run `neural_network = keras_model_sequential() %>% layer_dense(units = 50, activation = "relu", input_shape = ncol(x)) %>% layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% layer_dense(units = 1)`, I get

> `Error: Valid installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
C:\Users\alex\anaconda3\python.exe

Python exception encountered:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
return _run_hook(name, _hook)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
module = hook()
^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 117, in _hook
return *find_and_load(name, import*)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the exact code and the exact error it produces. See here for how to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: What I usually do is set up a conda env with tensorflow. And then set the global options in Rstudio (topic "Python") accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelM which options would you specify in particular?

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have other anoaconda/miniconda installations on your machine? Sometimes reticulate (the R package that communicates with your Python backend) has trouble using the "right" conda and environment in presence of other conda installations.

My advice:

- Check for other conda installations / setups, probably think about removing them (check with `reticulate::conda_list()` )
- Install miniconda via reticulate (`reticulate::install_miniconda()`)
- Install tensorflow dependencies via `tensorflow::install_tensorflow()` or `keras::install_keras()`.

Troubleshooting:

- MacOS users with M1/M2/M3: you have to set up your tensorflow environment yourself, here is a description how to do it https://theoreticalecology.github.io/machinelearning/A1-GettingStarted.html

Comment: I think I have miniconda installed already, I tried running the line you suggested in the second bulletpoint, and it said 'Miniconda is installed already at path ....'